# Display Images in Apex 5 report

Tags: image, report, apex, oracle-apex-5, oracle-apex-5.1

How can I load images dynamically in place of cell data in a report in Oracle Application Express 5.1?

For expample I want to display the pencil icon if `PARAMETERLIST_ID_FK` does not end with `_cYtD`:

```
select ID,
       PARAMETERLIST_ID_FK,
       STEPS_ID_FK,
        DECODE(substr(PARAMETERLIST_ID_FK),-5)
            ,'_cYTD',NULL,'<img src="#IMAGE_PREFIX#app_ui/img/icons/apex-edit-pencil.png" class="apex-edit-pencil" alt="">') Edit 
 from RAWDATA_PARAMETER RP
```

In Apex 4, this has worked. How can I convert it into Apex 5.1?

Comment: I found the answer the report, changed  "escape special characters" to NO in the "security" section of the column

Answer (score -1):

Another Way To Show An image In your Report is

Change your column type to LINK Then You Can use 
Link Text :

```
<img src="#IMAGE_PREFIX#app_ui/img/icons/apex-edit-pencil-alt.png" class="apex-edit-pencil-alt" alt="">
```

Comment: You've right normally this work, but in the specific case, it was needed to display the link only for some of the values in the column